# How can I load the MathJax in angular view from database?

Tags: angular, mathjax

I want to load the MathJax in the angular view. I am storing the HTML data along with MathJax equations in the database. When the view loads, the data is pulled from the database and displayed on the page using the [innerHTML] tag.

I am not able to see the MathJax equations on the view when loaded. I have imported the MathJax https://www.mathjax.org/ website and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please show some code on how you're trying. Also take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-angular to use MathJax in Angular.

Comment: @MichaelD

`equation = "<p>In elementary algebra, the <b>quadratic formula</b> is the solution of the quadratic equation.</p>

 <p style="text-align: center;"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mrow><mo>-</mo><mi>b</mi><mo>±</mo><msqrt><msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mn>4</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi></msqrt></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>a</mi></mrow></mfrac></math></p>"
this is the data i am loading from database and adding to a variable in angular component.

In HTML file I am using
<div [innerHTML]="equation"></div>

Comment: @ruth, I have installed the Mathjax-angular package and I see below error:
ERROR in node_modules/mathjax-angular/directive/mathjax.directive.d.ts:12:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/mathjax-project/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

    12     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<MathjaxDirective, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    node_modules/mathjax-angular/directive/mathjax.directive.d.ts:13:21 - error TS2694: Namespace